# English translation of Madhva Bhashya on Mandukya Upanishad

Tags: translation-request, mandukya-upanishad

I am looking for translation of following Bhashya text of Madhvacharya on Mandukya Upanishad

> तां सृष्टिं बहुधा प्राहुः ज्ञानिनोऽज्ञानिनस्तथा ।
>   विष्णर्विकृतिमायाति महदादिस्वरूपीणीम् ।
>    तत्तद्विविधभूतिरस्तु सृष्टिः प्रोक्ता ह्यपण्डितैः ।
>   स्वप्नमायासरूपां च केचिदज्ञा जनाः विदुः ।
>
> अविकारस्यचिन्मात्रस्वेच्छयैवाखिलं जगत् ।
>   उत्पद्यत इति प्राज्ञाः प्राहुर्ब्रह्मादयोऽखिलाः ।
>   पूर्णशक्तेः कुतो माया सर्वज्ञात् स्वप्नवत् कुतः ।
>   सर्वदोषव्यतीतस्य विकारः कुत ईष्यते ।
>
> तस्मादेवाविकारस्य विष्णोरिच्छावशादिदम् ।
>   यथार्थमेव संभूतमिति वेदवाचोऽखिलम् ।
>   केचित्कालात् एवैतां सृष्टिमाहुरकोविदाः ।
>   केचिद्रुद्राद्ब्रह्माश्चप्रधानादिति चापरे।
>
> विमूढाः सर्वे एवैते यतो नारायणः पराः ।
>   सर्वकर्ता सर्वशक्तिरैक एव न चापरः ।
>   प्रधानकालब्रह्मेश सर्वेऽपि तद्वशाः ॥

Is there English translation of Madhva Bhashya available?

Comment: What is reference of this mantra ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It is Madhva Bhashya on Mandukya Upanishad Agama karika 6 to 9

Comment: Translation of the verses can be available on the internet if found. Our site is for asking significance and interpretation only. Literal translations are off-topic. We are not translators.Our site is an English language site. Post the transliteration of verse and ask for significance of it. Otherwise, it will be closed as off-topic or unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Indra Don't just copy paste mantra like this. We can't do the translation for you. You have to give proper reference of mantra and you may ask the interpretation of it. In any case check ["How to ask"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Leave this as it was and ask this as a new question. The answers should not become obsolete and the question should not change completely. Because first you asked the translation and now you continue the question with unrelated verses. I am removing that part. So, let this question closed and ask the new edit as a new question.It won't become a duplicate question. Please avoid ask translation questions again.

Comment: @Pandya the OP asked about translation of the verses and not where can he find translation. Both are different questions. We need not to add new questions just to reopen questions.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, I think translation of scriptural verses should be allowed.

Comment: @Pandya It is against faq now. Why to throw away already discussed faq? Why is this sudden decision taken without any discussion or any announcement? How will others understand a "moderator's thought" without a meta or a discussion?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is translation request

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sanskrit  passage you quoted in the question for the translation request is from Shree Madhvacharya's sanskrit commentary on [**Mandukya Upanishad Chapter -1, Kārikās – 6 to 9**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/kaarikaa.html?lang=sa) . Which are as follows.

> प्रभवः सर्वभावानां सतामिति विनिश्चयः । 
>  सर्वं जनयति
>   प्राणश्चेतोंऽशून्पुरुषः पृथक् ॥ 1.6॥
>
> There is no doubt whether Vishnu is the energizer of all the emotions
>   (creatures). The noble ones were thus assured .those who think
>   otherwise are the ignoble. Being the energizer of all, Primal Breath
>   takes upon the task, Narayana remaining to be the supreme.
>
> विभूतिं प्रसवं त्वन्ये मन्यन्ते सृष्टिचिन्तकाः ।
>  स्वप्नमायासरूपेति
>   सृष्टिरन्यैर्विकल्पिता ॥ 1.7॥
>
> Creation is conceived through modification, thus think the thinkers of
>   creation. Creation is formatted as in a dream, think other thinkers of
>   creation. .
>
> इच्छामात्रं प्रभोः सृष्टिरिति सृष्टौ विनिश्चिताः ।
>  कालात्प्रसूतिं
>   भूतानां मन्यन्ते कालचिन्तकाः ॥ 1.8॥
>
> By mere Will of the Lord is this Creation, thus have others concluded
>   ; evolved by Time is this creation, thus consider the protagonists of
>   Time.
>
> भोगार्थं सृष्टिरित्यन्ये क्रीडार्थमिति चापरे ।
>  देवस्यैष
>   स्वभावोऽयमाप्तकामस्य का स्पृहा ॥ 1.9||
>
> This world is for enjoyment (of the Lord) say some, others consider it
>   for (His) diversion. Both these are but his attributes, what indeed is
>   there for self-satisfied one to have desires ?

---

And here is the English translation of your sanskrit passage which is Shree Madhvacharya's sanskrit commentary with english translation . [**Sri Madhva Mandukya Upanishad  By: Nagesh D. Sonde**](http://nageshsonde.com/images/Sri_Madhva_Mandukya_Upanishad.pdf)  - PDF -Page 14.

> तां सृष्टिं बहुधा प्राहुः ज्ञानिनोऽज्ञानिनस्तथा । विष्णर्विकृतिमायाति
>   महदादिस्वरूपीणीम् । तत्तद्विविधभूतिरस्तु सृष्टिः प्रोक्ता ह्यपण्डितैः
>   । स्वप्नमायासरूपां च केचिदज्ञा जनाः विदुः ।
>   अविकारस्यचिन्मात्रस्वेच्छयैवाखिलं जगत् । उत्पद्यत इति प्राज्ञाः
>   प्राहुर्ब्रह्मादयोऽखिलाः । पूर्णशक्तेः कुतो माया सर्वज्ञात् स्वप्नवत्
>   कुतः । सर्वदोषव्यतीतस्य विकारः कुत ईष्यते । तस्मादेवाविकारस्य
>   विष्णोरिच्छावशादिदम् । यथार्थमेव संभूतमिति वेदवाचोऽखिलम् ।
>   केचित्कालात् एवैतां सृष्टिमाहुरकोविदाः ।
>   केचिद्रुद्राद्ब्रह्माश्चप्रधानादिति चापरे । विमूढाः सर्वे एवैते यतो
>   नारायणः पराः । सर्वकर्ता सर्वशक्तिरैक एव न चापरः । प्रधानकालब्रह्मेश
>   सर्वेऽपि तद्वशाः ॥
>
> This creation is spoken variously by the wise as well by the ignorant
>   ones. It is the manifestation of Vishnu’s formative power (maayaa)
>   giving shape to Mahat and others elements, say some wise ones;
>   Creation the form of an illusion seen in dreams say other ignorant
>   ones. For the formless One, the entire creation is possible to
>   manifest by mere Self-Will, Brahma and all others having been thus
>   evolved, say some wise ones. For one who is allpowerful how can there
>   be illusion; for one who is Wisdom personified how can there be
>   objects as in a dream? For one who is devoid of any defects, how can
>   there be any deformity ? Therefore, free from any defects is this
>   Creation, subservient to Sri Vishnu’s Will. Creation is authenticated
>   by many statements of Vedas. Some ignorant ones argue that out of Time
>   has Creation has come to be evolved ; some consider it to be from
>   Rudra, some others from Brahma and still others from Prakriti. Fools
>   are all these, when Narayana alone is the Supreme, all-powerful
>   Creator and no one else, Time, Brahma, Shiva and all others being
>   subservient to Him.

**Brief Summary of Shree Madhvacharya's point of view in above passage. -:** 
Basically here Shree Madhvacharya advocating his Dvaita theory through this commentary and is praising Vishnu or Narayana  and is saying that Narayana or Shree Vishnu alone  is the   supreme being and sustainer  , energizer of the universe . This all creation is Shree Vishnu's will . 
He is also in his  the passage quoted by you   refuting the other competitive  philosophies like Shankara's Mayavada. Theory of Creation of the universe  from Prakriti or(nature) or from deities like  Rudra and Brahma and all of these are subservient of Lord Vishnu. And all this creation is Leela of Narayana.

---

Here is [**Mandukya Upanishad**](https://archive.org/details/MandukyaUpanishadKarikaWithShankaraBhashya-SwamiNikhilananda) .

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't answer if the question is unclear. It only has Devanagari and not transliteration. Also,only translations are not done on our site. Significance of the verse should also be asked. Otherwise, our site will be flooded with translation requests. We are not translators. Wait for the modifications to be done by OP or modify to make the question ok then answer.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma So can we Modify a Question? If so, then how, I actually Have a doubt on a concept ?

Comment: @IndranilAmalDutta You should ask the concept alone and not translations of the verses. There are not many experts to translate. We too search from the internet just like you do.Please  don't ask direct translations. Post verses in transliterated format. Only English is allowed language.

Comment: @Indranil Click on the "edit" below the question and modify it.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Hope, now I've asked satisfactory Question, but my question is still isn't complete as the question section is not accepting more characters?

Comment: @IndranilAmalDutta The answer to this question is already accepted. Adding new questions makes the answer to be reformatted completely. It is better to leave question how it was. It is too late now. The gist of the question should not change completely. It has changed now. Ask this edit as a new question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Ok, If I ask a new Question on the same concept, even Though this one isn't complete, but won't it be considered as duplicated based on this Question?